# Can anyone give me an example of sdpTransform option in simplepeer

Tags: webrtc, sdp, simplewebrtc, simple-peer

Hi I've been searching for an example of how to use sdpTransform feature in simple peer and haven't found anything yet. Also is there any way to check what codecs were used in mediaStream object. Is there anyway to create custom sdp offer in SimplePeer.

Comment: Did my answer work?

Comment: Yes. It does thank you :).

Answer (score 1):

the parameter must contain a function that returns the transformed sdp. Found this github issue as example. [github](https://github.com/feross/simple-peer/issues/367)